# Django: How to access a list of backward relationships in a view?

Tags: python, django, relationship

let's assume, I have a model called Chicken:

```
class Chicken(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and I also have a model called Egg that has a ForeignKey to the Chicken-model:

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    chicken = models.ForeignKey(Chicken)
    layed_on = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

Now I want to create a view that contains a list of the all the chickens and the date when they layed their last egg.

I know how to get all eggs layed by a chicken, using something like this:

```
c = Chicken.objects.get(name='Henry')
e = c.egg_set.all()
```

But that doesn't really help, because I have a lot of chickens and I want to only get the date of their latest egg. I also don't know how to get that egg information into my view for easy access. In my view I would like to do something like this:

```
{% for chicken in chickens %}
    <p>{{ chicken.name }} layed is last egg on {{ chicken.last_egg }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm just a beginner and I would greatly appreciate any help you can give. The Django documentation does not really help me in this case.

Comment: Do you really need to know all the egg lay dates? If you don't, then you can keep a field in your Chicken model which is updated whenever a chicken lays an egg.

Comment: Yes, because in my real application (that is not really about chickens) I need more information than just the most recent date and I don't want to add all these fields to the Chicken-model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is django's annotation [feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).  Basically, you want to annotate each row in chicken with the `Max` of egg's layed_on field.  Without a prompt right in front of me, I can't guarentee the exact statement below, but it should give you a starting point.

Edit your chicken model like this:

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    chicken = models.ForeignKey(Chicken, related_name='eggs')
    layed_on = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)

from django.db.models import Max
Chicken.objects.annotate(last_egg=Max('eggs__layed_on'))
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with egg_set. I get a FieldError that says: "Cannot resolve keyword 'egg_set' into field."

Comment: See the edit above, use related_name on chicked foreign key, e.g. related_name='eggs', now instead of use egg_set use eggs.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to solve such a problem annotating methods in my models with the @property annotation.

An example: In your Chicken model, you would have a method like:

```
@property
def last_egg(self):
    return self.egg_set.order_by('-layed_on')[0]
```

And in your template, you could use it as a regular model field.

```
{{my_chicken.last_egg}}
```

I would additionally like to know if there are any issues about this solution, and what you guys think about it.
Maybe we could make this question a nice talk about how to ellegantly solve this issue.

Hope it helps.